# Boost python returning numpy array error

Tags: c++, arrays, numpy, boost

```
      boost::multi_array_ref<uint_pixel_type,9> vec= buf.array<uint_pixel_type>();
      npy_intp size = vec.num_elements();
      static_cast<double *>(NULL); 
      PyObject * pyObj = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData( 9, &size, NPY_DOUBLE, vec.data() );
      boost::python::handle<> handle( pyObj );
      boost::python::numeric::array arr( handle );
```

using this code , I am getting an

> error : ValueError: array is too big.